# ¿Por qué mi código no muestra el resultado?

Tags: php, html

hice un pequeño ejercicio con html y php donde me piden calcular el área de un triangulo, mi código quedó así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Formulario para poder calcular el area de un triangulo.</h1>
    <form action="triangulo.php">
        Dame la base: <input type=text name=base> <br> Dame la altura: <input type=text name=altura> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<?php
    $base = $_GET['base'];
    $altura = $_GET['altura'];
    $area=($base * $altura)/2;
    
    echo "El area es: $area";

?>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Ya intenté cambiando los metodos de _GET a _REQUEST, intenté modificar los nombre de las variables pero cuando intento introducir los datos en el formulario para que me haga la operación y me muestre el resultado no me arroja nada.

Comment: Te faltaría el método `post` o `get` después del `action` del formulario. Entre comillas los atributos en el `input` como `"base"` `"text"`.

Comment: @Bicho pero si no pones el action aún así lo debería de enviar por get, ¿no?

Comment: Yo he probado tu código y sí me funciona. El valor `Get` es el valor por defecto para `method`.

Comment: Tenés que colocar en el form  el method="post" y además cambia en las variables por _REQUEST . Además coméntanos sobre que versión de PHP estar trabajando.

Comment: ¿Estás abriendo el archivo php desde su ruta en disco o tienes un servidor local y accedes desde una URL como `http://localhost/triangulo.php`?

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y le hice algunas modificaciones.
Supongo que tu archivo se llama `triangulo.php` porque así definiste el `form action="triangulo.php"`. Verifica la extensión de tu archivo.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Formulario para poder calcular el area de un triangulo.</h1>
    <form action="triangulo.php">
        Dame la base: <input type=text name=base> <br>
        Dame la altura: <input type=text name=altura> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['base']) or !isset($_GET['altura'])) {
        echo "Ingresar valores a calcular";
    } else {
        $base = $_GET['base'];
        $altura = $_GET['altura'];
        $area=($base * $altura)/2;
        echo "El area es: $area";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, aparentemente era un error de mi versión de php, lo probé en un hosting y funcionó sin problemas, gracias.